# conditional formatting with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have 2 worksheets.  Worksheet 1 has 2 column STS and TICKER.  Worksheet 2 has TICKER.  I am trying to apply coniditional formatting on Worksheet 2 column TICKER when the TICKER is found on a row Worksheet one and the same row STS is = Y.  The problem I am running into is Worksheet 1 can have multiple rows of the TICK and the STS can be either Y or N.

So in condition when TICKER is the same and status Y, Y for the 2 records on Worksheet 1 the condition should work on TICKER on Worksheet 2.  If TICKER is Y,N for the 2 records on Worksheet 1 the condition still applies.  If the TICKER is N for all records or not found on WorkSheet 1 row then the condition should not apply.

I was using a countif statement to get the part with the TICKER workign but not sure how to include the STS.  =COUNTIF(Worksheet1!B:B,A2) >0

Comment: It would be better to understand if you post some of the data and an example of the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!$B:$B,A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,"Y")
```

where `STS` is in `Sheet1!A:A`
and `TICKER` is in `Sheet1!B:B`

adjust references to your reality.

*Note that since `FALSE` is equivalent to `0` in this case, there is no need to do an explicit comparison.*

Comment: Thanks so much! I actually tried doing this early to see if it would work but I got an error so you showing me was very helpful!